# How many distinct ways are there to get out in cricket?

Tags: rules, cricket

Recently I attended an interview, in which the interviewer asked me how many types of out are there in cricket.

I counted on my fingers and said 6. He said it was wrong and told me that there are a total of 11 outs.

What are they?

Comment: Out of curiosity, interview for what?

Comment: Maybe you can already add the six that you know to the question?

Comment: @ SigueSigueBen.... Interview for a software job. This is happened in HR(Human Resources) round. He asked me what's your habbies? I said playing cricket. So, he asked me this question.

Comment: @RanadheerReddy Hope he didn't hold your answer against you!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- *Bowled* (a delivery hits the stumps and dislodges a bail)
- *Timed out* (the batsman takes over 3 minutes to enter the field of play after a wicket falls)
- *Caught* (the batsman hits the ball and a fielder catches it before it bounces)
- *Handled the ball* (the batsman deliberately touches the ball with a hand that is not holding the bat)
- *Hit the ball twice* (the batsman deliberately hits the ball twice)
- *Hit wicket* (the batsman dislodges a bail with his person or bat)
- *Leg before wicket* (the batsman's person prevents a delivery from hitting the wicket)
- *Obstructing the field* (the batsman illegitimately obstructs the fielding side)
- *Run out* (the batsman's wicket is put down when he is outside his crease while attempting a run)
- *Stumped* (the striker's wicket is put down when he is outside his crease and not attempting a run)
- *Retired - out* (the batsman retires for any reason other than ["illness, injury or any other unavoidable cause"](http://www.lords.org/laws-and-spirit/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-2-substitutes-and-runners-batsman-or-fielder-leaving-the-field-batsman-retiring-batsman-commencing-innings,1338,AR.html))

Most of these explanations are oversimplifications - see the relevant Laws for the precise details.

Comment: What is "Retired - out"?

Comment: If a batsman retires without a reason such as injury, he is recorded as "Retired - out" on the score sheet.  This is always the tricky one in this kind of puzzle question.  There are only 10 ways to be dismissed in cricket, but there are 11 ways to appear as "out".  Both 10 and 11 could be considered correct answers, depending on how exactly you phrase the question.

Comment: Nice answer Peter Eisentraut.

Comment: @PeterEisentraut; what about mankading.

Comment: @gout. What is that meant ?

Comment: @gout: Mankading is a run out.

Comment: @PeterEisentraut. Yes, it comes under run out.I think Absent hurt is also a type of dismissal.

Comment: @RanadheerReddy. If a bowler during his delivery stride intentionally whips off the bails, in order to dismiss the non striker who is out of the crease. In recent times R Ashwin has done it in IPL as well as in CB series.

Comment: @gout: Absent hurt is not a dismissal or a way to get out.  A player who is absent by definition does not commence his innings, and therefore cannot be dismissed.  "Absent hurt" is only an entry in the score book for a player who did not bat when a side's innings was completed under Law 12.3 (b) (no further batsman available to come in).  The term "absent hurt" is not used in the laws or the ICC playing conditions.  Unlike the listed methods to get out, absent hurt and retired hurt do not count as an out in a player's career statistics, for example.

Comment: Could you add a short description to each out? as it is this list, while answering the question, doesn't really add much to this site.